# Setting up Responsive File Manager/TinyMce with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, responsive-filemanager

I've been trying to incorporate **Responsive File Manager** with Laravel 5.2, but I'm clueless as to how to upload picture (or any other resource) in my local machine.

I followed the installation on the official document, so now I can see the **TinyMce**'s template with **Responsive File Manager**'s icons.

The problems comes from when I click the **insert/edit image** icon and press the camera icon to upload a file. The error message is ...

`NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`

Also, I got the following message from the Google chrome's 'inspect'.

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`
`http://localhost:8000/js/filemanager/dialog.php?type=1&descending=false&lang=undefined&akey=key`

At least I can understand that...

1. When I click the icon, the icon invokes a GET method with the URL which is described above.
2. It is required to set a Route method with the URL

However, on the official document, I can't see where I can edit the URL and how the icons trigger a method.

I'd appreciate if you would give any advice!

Comment: Where is the official laravel link of `tinymyce`?

Comment: I mean, I followed the official document of **Responsive File Manager**, not `tinymce`.